# My first ever application for visa got denied under section 214(b)

Tags: usa, visa-refusals

I am doing my 1st year Master's degree in Biotechnology. I got selected for the Khorana Program for Scholars conducted by Indo-U.S. Science and technology forum, to do a 3 months internship at a U.S. University.

I have enough reasons to come back to India as I have to complete my Master's degree after returning so that I can apply for higher studies. There was a personal fund mentioned in my DS-2019 that is to be provided by my U.S. mentor as scholarship. I explained this in the interview. I didn't get any questions or asked for any documents to show my tie to my home country, although I brought everything with me.

What should I do next time to avoid visa rejection? Should I have provided them all the documents even if they didn't ask for it?

Comment: Have you ever travelled outside India before? Do you have any other ties to India apart from completing your studies? Don’t reapply on the same basis with the same evidence. Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133508/does-the-interview-for-a-us-b1-b2-visa-actually-influence-the-decision

Comment: No, I didn't ever travelled outside India. But everyone has a first time. I am traveling because I got scholarship that will cover all my travel and stay expenses otherwise I am not financial sound to travel internationally. As I am unmarried my only tie other than study is  that my parents and all my family are staying here and I have a bank account here. And yes I am getting scholarship of 8000 per month for my Master's degree.

Comment: Indeed, everyone does have a first time to travel. Unfortunately, where travel to the USA is concerned, it’s necessary to overcome their starting assumption of immigrant intent. That can be hard to achieve, if not impossible, for a first time traveller with relatively few strong ties to home.

Comment: So, can you help me out regarding how to overcome this.Many other scholars under this scholarship also travelled to USA for the first time. It's just an unfortunate case for me or should I have answered differently in my visa interview

Comment: "There was a personal fund mentioned in my DS-2019 that is to be provided my U.S. mentor as scholarship." - This is unclear to me. Whose fund is it? Who is your US mentor? Why is a personal fund mentioned at all in your DS-2019, which is supposedly filled out by the university department that will sponsor your visa. What is the currency of the 8000 you mentioned above? My suggestion is to talk to the department that sponsors your visa (J-1 if I'm guessing correctly) and ask them for advice.

Comment: That is the fund that my mentor a reagent professor at a premier university will provide for me as a scholarship for my stay. I had asked the international office of my US University to change the personal fund into specific grant from which I will get the scholarship. My indian scholarship that I am getting for my current M.Sc is in INR. But that shouldn't be a problem as my travel is completely sponsored. What else should I do to get approval in second time?

Comment: @richa : I once got rejected my visa .. for (lacking of economic and family ties) ... the agent  didnt ask me one single question (My earnings were for sure higher than his) ... 3 months later I applied I got my visa.

Comment: @M. Gara thank you for giving me hope. I have changed the funding category from my sponsor(personal fund to the specific grant name from where I will be getting my fund) and added some details about my current position as a student in the new DS160. I also have produced a resident certificate of my origin. Is it enough change of circumstances to approve of my visa?

Comment: @richa well here is the thing : it depends on the agent... and the current foreign policy of the country.. I wish you the best of luck dude. Hope that you will find someone who actually willing to read the file at least.