# Documents to take for B2 visa to confirm you are returning

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas

I am a final year B.Tech student in India. I am applying for tourist B2 visa to visit my sister studying in USA in summer immediately after my degree is complete. When visa officer asks for guarantee whether i will return to India after touring USA for few weeks, what reply should i give to convince him that i will? In my case the complication is that i am ripe for the age of job searching but i will not search for jobs in USA or stay back in USA. How to convince the visa officer despite the stereotypes? Also what documents to show him to guarantee that i will return to India?

Comment: That does not specifically address my case. I do not have a job at the moment. But i will surely not search for job in USA. How to convince the visa officer? He will think i have completed my degree and don't have a job. SO once i go to USA i will start looking for job. But i don't want the visa officers to think that.

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133508/does-the-interview-for-a-us-b1-b2-visa-actually-influence-the-decision

Comment: @heckehe We can only give general advice. All we know about you is the short paragraph you've written. Even if we knew all about you, we can't say anything specific because, ultimately, everything depends on the interpretation of the officers dealing with your application. If you believe that nothing on the linked page is applicable to you, then you should question whether you can give any demonstration at all that you will return to India beyond "I promise I'm honest and I promise I'll go."

Comment: @heckehe It’s not really a question of stereotypes, rather that the US starts from a position of assuming immigrant intent and the visa applicant has to prove the contrary. As David Richerby says, if the linked question doesn’t help you, then ask yourself whether you can make a credible case at all.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You should ask yourself: Why am I going to return to India? The answer to this will suggest what documents, if any, you need to bring.