# US tourist Visa to attend a test prep course rejected (Sudan)

Tags: usa, tourist-visas, visa-rejections, sudanese-citizens

I'm a 22 year old medical graduate, graduated on December 13 last year (2018) and have a free period of 7 month before I start my medical foundation year in my country (sudan).

So I decided on taking advantage of this period of free time to prep for a master degree in the US or Canada.

I applied for a tourist Visa to the US in order to attend Kaplan's GRE prep course in Brooklyn New York (for a month period), that I have already payed for and got the enrolment letter and receipt, also I will attend another course in Morocco Casablanca in July 2019, after the GRE course, which I also have enrolment letter from...

I had all my papers ready enrolment letters, and certificate proving I have medical foundation year and civil service program due at the end of 2019.
Yet I got my Visa rejected after only 4 questions, noting that my cousin who is a us citizen payed for my course, and the expenses of the trip will be payed by my family, which I got bank statement proving so.
I haven't even got the opportunity to show my documents and only got asked what is the cause of visit and whom will be paying for my trip.

My question: why did my Visa get rejected without the consulate 
officer reviewing all the documents that will prove I will be returning to Sudan?

I am planning on applying again for a second time immediately to catch the course that I already payed for, should I apply again? And what advice you can offer?

Comment: As a young person with relatively few strong ties to your home country and with family in the US, it seems likely you failed to overcome the assumption of immigrant intent. Your chances of success with a second application are probably pretty low unless your personal circumstances have changed. See for example https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133508/does-the-interview-for-a-us-b1-b2-visa-actually-influence-the-decision

Comment: Thank you for your response. My only strong tie is the fact  that I have a medical foundation year awaiting for me in Sudan without it I can not get my license to practice medicine or get my Bachelor authenticated, and also my next trip to Casablanca,  is in that enough in anyway, because I have not got the chance to explain that in interview, and is it better to explain it on the d-160 ?

Answer (score 8):

We get a steady trickle of questions from people whose US visa application was rejected after an apparently perfunctory in-person interview. It appears that they have a rule that they *must* conduct in-person interviews for all applicants even when they've already decided based on the written application to reject it. (But I don't think we have *found* such an explicit rule state in so many words in any official document).

In your question and the comment below it, it looks like you were hoping to support your application on documents *which you did not mention in the application*, expecting to disclose them only at the interview. That is a common theme in this kind of questions, and is by any means a recipe for failure.

**Always include all information you want to rely on with the visa application itself.** The countries that do visa interviews do it such that *they* can ask questions of *you* and gauge your reactions, not so *you* can blindside *them* with a sudden pile of papers and arguments you held back from the application.

After all, the purpose of needing to apply for a visa in advance is such that the bureaucracy can examine your supporting material *in their own time* and with less time pressure than if you show up at the immigration desk at the airport and expect a border guard to judge all your documents then and there. It would scarcely be an improvement to move that scene to a consulate instead.

Do not expect visa interviews to be a negotiation. They're not.

Comment: Thank you very much. You answer is totally reasonable, for instance I outsourced my Visa application process to an agency, where in the other hand I was readying my documents, contacting institutes and crafting my answers. I fairly suspected the case would be in the application. If you could advice me lastly if I should apply second time explaining what went wrong, and including all the documents in D-160, would I have a fair chance? Or it will be affected by the rejection of the last interview?

Comment: @Basiljelal After being here several years and trying to help hundreds of people, my advice is almost always to do the visa application yourself. Visa agencies are almost always a waste of money. They have no incentive to be sure that your visa is approved; rather they have the reverse incentive, to be sure that your visa is refused! so that you will try again and spend more money with them. It may take some time to learn the visa application process but it's generally worth it. You will have more confidence that you have done everything possible to secure the visa.