# Visa denial under section 214(B)

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, sudanese-citizens

I'm Sudanese and have previously travelled to Saudi Arabia, India, and England. I applied for a B1/B2 visa for a clinical elective through a travel agency.

I'm a medical student I still have 1 year to finish university, I live with one of my parents and I have a sick brother who I take care of. In the visa interview the officer didn't ask about why I will return and didn't give me the chance to explain it to him.

I want to reapply so I can explain my situation. Should I reapply immediately or wait for 6 months although I might lose my opportunity in this medical elective?

Comment: Do you have a strong previous travel history? Will anything in your personal circumstances change to strengthen your ties to home in the next 6 months, in order to better demonstrate non-immigrant intent? Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133508/does-the-interview-for-a-us-b1-b2-visa-actually-influence-the-decision

Comment: [Relevant answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134572/us-tourist-visa-to-attend-a-test-prep-course-rejected-sudan/134584#134584)

Comment: Did you explain and document your family and education situations in the original application?

Comment: You should not expect to be able to present anything at the US visa interview. Everything needs to be in your application.

Comment: @MichaelHampton there is no opportunity in the application to present anything other than a photograph.  The only forum for presenting supporting documents is the interview.