# B1 visa apply second time!

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I need your advice please. Any advice will be appreciated!
My first interview for B1 US visa was denied in 17th April. 2019 and I again applied to new interview with same purpose. Interview date is 25th April.
I wore suit with tie. And my interview started with nise VO.

VO: Good morning 
Me: Good morning sir.

VO: Can I have your passport 
Me: sure

VO: Where do you study 
Me: ABCD university PhD student

VO: what is your purpose 
Me: IEEE s&p conference

VO: how long you will stay
Me: 4 nights

VO: what your parents do?
Me: I said my father is taxist instead of( taxi driver)  my mom is seller

VO: sorry I don’t understand your father’s job
Me: again taxist instead of( taxi driver), after 2 secon I corrected my mistake he is taxi driver. Sorry

VO: have you been other countries (last question)
Me: no

VO:( gave me one yellow paper) everything is explained here. 
Me: Thank you very much( I read this Paper after leaving interview room. It was Section 214(b)
But I live with my wife in korea. It is not  strong tie? He did not asked about my marriage and supporting documents.
I had following documents:
-financial support ;
-letter of guarantee (returnt bact Korea);
-invitation letter;
-round trip ticket ;
-hotel booking;
1)I wanna give all of my docs with passport. Is it polite? How VO react for this situation?
2)Making mistake with my father’s job and correcting that mistake will it lead to a rejection?
3) what kind of questions I can expect in the 25th next interview? And how many % of chance I have for approving my visa in next immediate interview?
Thank you for sharing you time!

Comment: What information did you supply with your application? Did you add any evidence about your home ties between the two applications?

Comment: In the first application I wrote about my father mother and my spouse. Second one also same but I add my professor to “who go with you?”question. And I commented “Have you ever denied US visa?” Question Like this “Section 214(b) I must come back to korea becaus my wife will be alone if I will go to US. In addition I have letter of guarantee; financial support; ticket; invitation letter;”  is this also helpfull?

Comment: With one refusal already your chances are not good. Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133508/does-the-interview-for-a-us-b1-b2-visa-actually-influence-the-decision Possible duplicate of [How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country)

Comment: Although [How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/103826/19560) talks about presentation as being important, it appears that only matters if the application is good. The interview does not seem to be an opportunity to add information.

Comment: I wanna give all of my docs with passport. Is it polite? How VO react for this situation?

Comment: Why did you wait until the interview to bring those documents instead of enclosing them with your application?

Comment: @Ali If the application doesn’t look good on paper, anecdotal evidence on TSE indicates that the Immigration Officer will typically pay little attention to your paperwork. That is to say, in reality the decision will already have been made and the ‘interview’ has little bearing on the outcome.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "letter of guarantee (return back Korea)". A letter from you or anyone else promising that you will return to Korea is worthless because everybody would write such a letter. A round trip ticket also doesn't prove anything, since you could stay in the US and not use the return half. Indeed, as I recall, the US specifically says not to buy tickets before your visa has been granted, to avoid you wasting money if your application is rejected.

Comment: I can understand the reluctance to accept extra documents during the interview. Checking that a document is genuine may require comparing it to known good samples, showing it to someone familiar with that type of document, examining it with a magnifying glass looking for alternations, making phone calls etc. The real problem is that there does not seem to be any way to reject an application for insufficient documentation without going through the motions of an interview.

Comment: The US visa interview is largely a formality, and it is unlikely that anything will be accepted at the interview. Everything you want to present should be included with your original application.

Comment: @Henning Makholm, Michael Hampton, For example my wife is pregnant and she will give birth after my trip to US and we have not relatives to take care of my wife if I will go to US or if I have PhD thesis defense after my trip. So, in this situation which section of DS-160 form I can enclose or input those informations? In ds160 form I think there is no section or part to add this kind of circumstances I mean you can only answer what ds160 system ask, is there additional part to explain your strong ties?

Comment: In addition,  I thought during the interview process VO did not see information about my spouse who lives with me in Korea, therefore when I was filling new DS-160 in travel information part there was a question "Have you ever been refused a U.S. Visa?, Explain" I wrote a comment   " SECTION 214(B). I CAN ASSURE YOU THAT I MUST COME BACK BECAUSE I LIVE WITH MY SPOUSE, SHE WILL BE ALONE IF I WILL GO TO US AND I HAVE A STUDY HERE. IN ADDITION, MY TRIP SUPPORTED FINANCIALLY BY UNIVERSITY, I HAVE A GUARANTEE LETTER, ROUND TRIP TICKET AND INVITATION LETTER" what do you think is this okay?

Comment: I think there is a non-duplicate question here. The OP apparently assumed that it would be OK to make undocumented assertions in the application and then supply the supporting documents during the interview. Experience of TSE questioners indicates that new documents are not accepted, and the application is likely to be rejected based on the lack of supporting documents. Given that situation, what should the OP do now? Attend the interview and try to hand the officer the documents? Cancel the application and submit a new one with documents?