# Preparing 2nd B1 visa interview

Tags: b1-b2-visas

Good morning. The first of all I want to say a great thanks to this site and advisors who are sharing their valuable time. 
Tomorrow I will have a 2nd interview, so I am preparing now. 
May I answer VO questions like below?

VO: what has changed from the last interview?

Me: I enclose my professor’s name to my new application form. He will go with me and we will stay together in one room in Hyatt Regency in San Francisco. And I have a letter of guarantee from my professor.   In addition, I live with my wife and nowadays we are trying to conceive, if I will go to the US she will be alone therefore I must come back to Korea and continue my study

VO:  What is your purpose to go to the US?

Me: Participating IEEE Symposium and Workshops on Security and Privacy which is a great opportunity to get knowledge from Microsoft, Google and other information security experts, and I 100% believe that this conference will nourish my research ability.

My answers are Okay or are they too long?

In addition, I want to give my all documents with my passport to VO, what do you think is this not impolite?

Comment: How come it’s so easy to *add* a professor to the application?

Comment: @Ali What do you mean by ‘give all my documents with my passport to VO’? Haven’t you already submitted all your documents with your application (see comments on your previous question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/136062/b1-visa-apply-second-time)?

Comment: I think you are attaching far, far too much significance to the interview, and nowhere near enough to preparing the application, especially to making sure the application itself contains documents supporting each assertion.

Comment: Dear @Traveller Visa officer did not ask any supporting documents in previous interview. He took only my passport. In new interview I wanna give my marriage certificate, ticket, financial support, ..etc to visa officer

Comment: Dear @Hanky Panky I just enclose my professor name. There was question “Who will go with you?” In ds160

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you did not add substantial documentation to your application, I am afraid there is no reason to expect anything different from the interview described in your previous question, [B1 visa apply second time!](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/136062/19560). That is, the most likely outcome is a few questions, followed by a rejection.

The documents are needed during processing of the application. Weight will be given to those aspects of the application that are supported by documents **attached to the application**.

The interviewer has neither the time nor the facilities for verifying documents. Accepting documents during the interview would make forgeries more effective. During application processing a document can be compared to known good samples, examined by someone familiar with that sort of document, and checked in various ways.

The interview is a combination of a required formality and an opportunity to detect an applicant who had someone else prepare a fictitious application and does not really know what it says. You were not asked for documents during the previous interview because document review is not part of the interview. Attempting to hand the interviewer additional documents with your passport may or may not be considered impolite, but, based on anecdotal evidence in questions here, it is unlikely to persuade the interviewer to review the documents and take them into consideration.

I hope I am wrong, and wish you luck.

Comment: @ Patrica Shanahan Thank you so much for sharing your time!