# What is the easiest way to get US visa?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, work, uzbek-citizens

Some tips to get it? How should I behave in the interview?
I have one reject of J-1 Visa, like work and travel, can it affect on my interview conclusion?

Comment: There are no easy ways to get a visa. Apply the right way with all the right information. As you do not give information about yourself we can not help you much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the interview for a US B1/B2 visa actually influence the decision?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133508/does-the-interview-for-a-us-b1-b2-visa-actually-influence-the-decision)

Comment: @Feliks_JS Your question is too broad. What visa do you want to apply for? Why was your J-1 visa application refused and when? What is your citizenship? There are a lot of questions on TSE about US visas, try searching  https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5194/us-visas-overview-community-wiki-to-avoid-duplicates and then edit your question to make it more specific

Comment: J-1 is restricted to few countries. Maybe you just didn't qualify for it. Visa that allows you to works are difficult to have, because you may get cheaper jobs, instead of US citizen. And it may indicate a intention to immigrate (so more difficult to proof the contrary). Remember in US the officers should, by laws, think that you want to immigrate. They must be convinced to the contrary.

Comment: thanks for the answers, i am from Uzbekistan, country in Central Asia, 20-25 years old, pretty young, want to get work visa for US, dont want to immigrate, but the thing is that , Visa Oficers will just look at my age and think that i am young, full of power, and that i am definitely gonna stay there , immigrate, but how can i proove them that i WILL NOT stay there??? i mean immigrate! Thanks in advance! BTW i am software Developer , maybe this can help me

Comment: Your question belongs on our sistersite Expatriates Stack Exchange.  But I feel it still lacks details. US immigration will assume you will want to stay as they assume that from everybody who wants to work in the US.

Comment: @Feliks_JS Saying you want a work visa but that you don’t want to immigrate is contradictory. I’d guess that software developers are 10 a penny in the US, as they are in many highly developed countries. Do you have any specialist development skills that are hard for employers to come by? If you can leave Uzbekistan for a job in the US for a presumably indefinite period, what do you leave behind in Uzbekistan that would compel you to return to your home country? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country